# glVertexAttribPointer() can't find valid context on Wayland environment?

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl, xorg, wayland

I try to draw colorized triangle. I want to use modern OpenGL and translate data via vertex attrib array.

*Vertex shader and Fragment shader just pass color from input to output and don't contain any interesting code*

```
pg.init()

triangle = np.array( triangle, dtype=np.float32 )
triangle_buffer = glGenBuffers( 1 )

glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangle_buffer )
glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangle.nbytes, triangle, GL_STATIC_DRAW )

vertex_shader = compileShader( vertex_src, GL_VERTEX_SHADER )
fragment_shader = compileShader( fragment_src, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER )
shader_program = compileProgram( vertex_shader, fragment_shader )
glUseProgram( shader_program )

glEnableVertexAttribArray( 0 )
glVertexAttribPointer( 0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, triangle.itemsize * 6, ctypes.c_void_p( 0 ) )
```

when I try to run this program an exception throws.

```
OpenGL.error.Error: Attempt to retrieve context when no valid context

Process finished with exit code 1
```

what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. `app = App()` and `app.run()` works fine.

Comment: Huh! after swiching Wayland to Xorg it's work!

Comment: on Wayland it's need to add env PYOPENGL_PLATFORM=x11 and it's work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's need to swich `Wayland` to `Xorg` at login time! On Wayland you can add env variable `PYOPENGL_PLATFORM=x11`.